# sql query cast issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 'C:\' + full_path + '\' + full_name
```

But it's giving me the following error:

```
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

I have tried changing the query to:

```
SELECT 'C:\' + full_path + '\' + cast(full_name as varchar(255))
```

But that gives me:

```
C:\path\3.68954e+006.doc
```

instead of something like `c:\path\3689541.doc`

Comment: Where are you getting the data from - Excel? What data type is it stored as?

Comment: What type is `full_name` ?

Comment: If it's having trouble converting `full_name` it seems to imply that the data type is some numeric (float, real, decimal, etc.)  What's odd is that you say the result ends with `.doc`. How can that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`str()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) instead:

```
 SELECT 'C:\' + full_path + '\' + ltrim(str(full_name, 10, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should try this

```
  SELECT 'C:\' + full_path + '\' + CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,2),fullname))
```

Comment: basing on the error @Yuck i have analyzing the data type and giving solution.For that kind of error what will be the solution like that I'm moving